# gpupdate with powershell

Tags: powershell, wait, updating, group-policy

I want to perform a `gpupdate` as an `-Action` of a `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` instance but gpupdate occasionally hangs completely when being called from PowerShell. I have tried the following way to handle an inresponsive gpupdate but it does not work as expected - the whole script still hangs when gpupdate goes wrong.

```
$command = "/target:computer"

$gp = Start-Process -FilePath gpupdate `
      -ArgumentList $command -NoNewWindow -PassThru 
wait-process -inputobject $gp -timeout 10    

if( $gp.HasExited -ne $true )
{
    stop-process -inputobject $gp -force
    $errcode = 99
}
else
{
    $errcode = $gp.exitcode
}
```

My questions are

- Has anyone experienced similar problems with `gpupdate` being called from PowerShell (v2); what could be the reason for that?
- Why does the above code snippet not do what I expect it to do (i.e. why does the `wait-process`-command not really shutdown the gpupdate process when the latter is inresponsive)?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried adding the `/wait` Parameter but it did not change anything. I have also tried the following code:

```
    $gp = Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName "localhost"`
         -EnableAllPrivileges`
         -Path win32_process -Name "create"`
         -ArgumentList "gpupdate /target:Computer /wait:5"
```

with `$gp.ReturnValue` as `$errcode`, but the problem remains. I still dont get a response from the script after several runs and the subscriber stops firing.
After trying the whole thing with `start-job` and `wait-job` which did not solve it either, I am at my wit's end.

- Is there a better option to perform this task?
- Is it worth to read up on powershell error handling?

Comment: Maybe you could add the /wait parameter. See here: http://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy/understanding-the-group-policy-gpupdate-command/

Comment: Thank you. I will try this as it is likely to solve my problem. (Though it still remains mysterious to me, why the code above does not work as intended...)

Comment: I tried it but for some strange reason it didnt work as desired. I have also updated my question. Maybe you've got some more ideas on this? Thanks in advance!